# Kotlin Promises Kovenant traning

Tags: android, kotlin, promise, kovenant

I'm trying to use Kovenant with kotlin. 
[Referring this link](https://github.com/mplatvoet/kovenant) in my app fetching data from imdb api using , Anko,
Fuel //for http ,
Injekt //for dependency injection. I dont have any errors in my whole code. but there is 2 runtime ERROR. in this lines

`val resultPromise = fuelService.textUrl(baseURL, listOf( "q" to  "movie/top_rated"`

errors are these exceptions :

> Caused by: uy.kohesive.injekt.api.InjektionException: No registered instance or factory for type class com.ik.navigationjetpack.utils.FuelHttpService**
>   and
>
> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ik.navigationjetpack/com.ik.navigationjetpack.MovieDb}: uy.kohesive.injekt.api.InjektionException: No registered instance or factory for type class com.ik.navigationjetpack.utils.FuelHttpService**

ı cant found anything about it. is there any clear and basic tutorial for promises using api in android?

Comment: It looks like you are missing some dependencies (or factories for them) it looks more like an error from Injekt than kovenant

Comment: I think if I miss dependency , ı cannot use ınject annotations, because of build issues. but ı dont know anything about factories.

Comment: How are you providing the "FuelHttpService" instance to Injektion? How is "FuelHttpService" defined?